# Running application with WPF WebBrowser as other user than currently logged in - some web pages not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, multi-user

I'm trying to run WPF WebBrowser as other user than currently logged in (using powershell `Start-Process -FilePath "app.exe" -Credentials xxx`. Unfortunately some websites not working properly, for example microsoft support pages - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/923196/you-receive-an-error-message-that-states-that-you-do-not-have-the-most.
The issue is, that these pages are not fully loading - I'm getting `"Script Error"` or `"An internal error occurred in Microsoft Internet Extensions"`exceptions and page remains blank (only part of site source code was loaded). Do anyone know what's going on? Is there anything, that should be configured in WebBrowser, to run it at other user?

Steps to reproduce:

```
1) Create simple WPF app and add WebBrowser control to it.    
2) Run app using "Start-Process" using powershell or "runas" using cmd as other 
user than currently logged in and navigate to
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/923196/you-receive-an-error-message-that-states-that-you-do-not-have-the-most    
3) Issue occured
```

Regards,
Hawex

Answer (score 0):

I found, that solution for this issue is simple - just need to add `-LoadUserProfile` argument in `powershell` or `/noprofile` in `runas`.